# How to get last 90 days data from today

Tags: informix

I am trying to get last 90 days data from today — is there any function in Informix to do that?

Like in other SQL:

```
Select * from table1 where DATEADD(d,-90,getdate())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE d >= TODAY - 90
```

I'm assuming the column `d` in table `Table1` is of type `DATE` or `DATETIME YEAR TO DAY` (or more precise but including `YEAR`).

Choose your poison on `>` vs `>=`.

Informix does not have a `DATEADD` function, or a `GETDATE()` function.  The built-in zero-argument (no parentheses) function `TODAY` yields today's date as a `DATE` value; the function `CURRENT YEAR TO DAY` yields it as `DATETIME YEAR TO DAY`.  You can simply use `+` and `-` to add or subtract an integer number of days to a `DATE` value (or subtract two `DATE` values to get the integer number of days between them).  You typically end up using expressions such as `CURRENT YEAR TO DAY - 90 UNITS DAY` if you have to work with `DATETIME` instead of `DATE` values.

Comment: How to ignore weekends?